# Pacote bayesQR Mensagem de erro

Tags: r

Estou tentando replicar o seguinte exemplo deste pacote "bayesQR": [bayesQR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesQR/bayesQR.pdf)

```
set.seed(66)
n <- 200
X <- runif(n=n,min=0,max=10)
X <- X
y <- 1 + 2*X + rnorm(n=n, mean=0, sd=.6*X)
# Estimate series of quantile regressions with adaptive lasso
out <- bayesQR(y~X, quantile=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95), alasso=TRUE, ndraw=5000)
```

No entanto, obtenho a seguinte  mensagem:

```
Error in bayesQR(y ~ X, quantile = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), alasso = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (quantile = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), alasso = TRUE, ndraw = 5000)
```

Quando faço

```
out <- bayesQR(y~X, .5)
```

A estimação se desenvolve naturalmente.

Por que a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mensagem está falando que os argumentos `quantile`, `alasso` e `ndraw` não fazem parte da função `bayesQR`.

O que isso quer dizer é que você está usando outra função chamada `bayesQR` que não é do pacote `bayesQR`. Se você reiniciar o R e carregar apenas o pacote `bayesQR` e rodar novamente o exemplo ele irá funcionar normalmente. Ou você pode rodar seu código da seguinte forma:

```
out <- bayesQR::bayesQR(y~X, quantile=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95), alasso=TRUE, ndraw=5000)
```

Assim você terá certeza de que está rodando a função `bayesQR` do pacote `bayesQR`.

Dando uma pesquisada, é muito provável que você tenha carregado o pacote [`factorQR` que, por coincidência, tem uma função com o mesmo nome,isto é, `bayesQR`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factorQR/functions/bayesQR). Dessa forma, você estava chamando a função  `factorQR::bayesQR` ao invés de `bayesQR::bayesQR` e por isso a mensagem de erro, uma vez que as funções tem argumentos diferentes.

Veja:

```
library(factorQR)
out <- bayesQR(y~X, quantile=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95), alasso=TRUE, ndraw=5000)
Error in bayesQR(y ~ X, quantile = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), alasso = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (quantile = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), alasso = TRUE, ndraw = 5000)
```